# Regex did not get each matched item from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need help on a regex pattern.

I have this string:

```
test = "/*testing 1*/Name: /*Testing 2*/ My Name"
```

I need to remove each `/**contents **/` from the string.

I am using regex to do the filtering as following code:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"/\*[^>]+\*/");
Template = rx.Replace(Template, match => { return String.Empty; });
```

but the result I am getting is only **" My Name"**, the expected result is **"Name: My Name"**.

Answer (score 4):

Change your regex to `/\*[^>]+?\*/`.

The `?` after the `+` makes it non greedy so the regex stops at the first `*/` instead of the last. Be aware though that if you have nested `/* ... */` blocks the regex will fail.